# React with AntDesign Lists and Firebase Firestore Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, antd

I'm trying to figure out how to present data from firestore in a react app, using Ant Design's List.

The List is set up like so:

```
const data = [
  {
    title: 'Ant Design Title 1',
  },

  <List
    itemLayout="horizontal"
    dataSource={data}
    renderItem={item => (
      <List.Item>
        <List.Item.Meta
          avatar={<Avatar src="https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png" />}
          title={<a href="https://ant.design">{item.title}</a>}
          description="Ant Design, a design language for background applications, is refined by Ant UED Team"
        />
      </List.Item>
    )}
  />
```

I want to try to put firebase data into the const data - so that the title can be a user.name.

In my component I have:

```
{loading && <div>Loading ...</div>}
{users.map(user => (
            <li key={user.uid}>
```

I'm trying to convert this to work with Ant Design's list like so:

```
const data = [
    {
      //title: `{user.name}`,
      title: {user.name},

    }
];
<List

    itemLayout="horizontal"
    dataSource={data}
    renderItem={users.map(user => (
    // renderItem={item => (
      <List.Item>
        <List.Item.Meta
        //   avatar={<Avatar src="https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png" />}
          title={item.title}
          description="Ant Design, a design language for background applications, is refined by Ant UED Team"
        />
      </List.Item>
    ))}
  />
```

When I try this, I get an error that says:

```
TypeError: renderItem is not a function
```

Is there an example of how to put data into an Ant Design list using react?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your firebase `users` source is an array of objects then just add it directly to `dataSource` prop.

```
  <List
    itemLayout="horizontal"
    dataSource={users}
    renderItem={item => (
      <List.Item>
        ...
      </List.Item>
    )}
  />
```